# Undefined value from text area in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am creating one form using Bootstrap & AngularJS. I am using CK editor in my page as `textarea`. But I am not able to retrieve the value of the `textarea` while the value of the input text field is easily captured in my AngularJS controller. Following is the code snippet:

**HTML page:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="controller">
        <form role="form">

            <label for="sd"><b>Short Description: </b></label>

            <input ng-model="sdesc" class = "form-control input-xxlarge" type = "text" placeholder ="Provide a short description here."/>    

            <br/>
            <label for="dt"><b>Details: </b></label>

            <textarea ng-model="details" class="form-control" name="details_editor" id="details_editor"></textarea>

            <br/>

            <button class = "btn btn-primary" ng-click="submitted()">Ask It!</button>             

            <script>
                        CKEDITOR.replace('details_editor');
            </script>
        </form>
    </div>

<br/>
<hr>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('controller', ['$scope', function($scope){
       $scope.submitted = function(){
           var sdesc = $scope.sdesc;
           var details = $scope.details;

           alert($scope.details);
       };
}]);
```

The alert shows `undefined` for the text area value.

Please help me solve the issue.

Comment: I think the CK replaces the textarea, check out DOM after page renders OR do it like `$timeout(function(){ console.log($scope.details) })` to check if it's digest problem

Comment: Hey @maurycy - I am actually pretty new to web development. So can you please tell me more about what to do. After rendering the page, when I do inspect element, I see the text area is represented by some other DOM element which are created dynamically by the CK editor itself. So what is the correct way to get the data?

Comment: If you do the `console.log` inside `$timeout` as per my comment it should work and the reason why is that `$timeout` in angular schedule the `$digest` cycle (you should read about it in more details if you are new to web development - it's angular specific process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the plain Javascript version of CK editor and hence Angular is not getting notified to update the `ng-model` value of that `textarea`.

Basically, Angular runs a digest cycle to update all views and models but since in this case the values being changed in the CK editor is happening outside the Angular.s context which is not updating the `ng-model` value.

To fix this, we added a small directive and notifying the change in the `ng-model` to the Angular by using the `$timeout`. (We can also use the `$apply` directive, but it may fail sometimes if the digest cycle is already in progress)

Example directive:

```
var app = angular.module("your-app-name", []);
app.directive("ckEditor", ["$timeout", function($timeout) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(element[0]);
            console.log(element[0], editor);

            editor.on("change", function() {
                $timeout(function() {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(editor.getData());
                });
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function (value) {
                editor.setData(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

Remove, your following code:

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('details_editor');
</script>
```

And, modify your text-editor like:

```
<textarea ng-model="details" class="form-control" ck-editor name="details_editor" id="details_editor"></textarea>
```

Comment: Not able to make it work. When I use your directive implementation, the text area changes to default text area of bootstrap.

Comment: I added a log in the directive. Can you please re-try that and tell me the output of that log.

Comment: But can you tell how angular js references 'CKEDITOR' inside app.js?

Comment: Glad that is working. `CKEDITOR` variable is provided by the CKEditor library and that variable is available globally in the Javascript context. So it is simply available inside the AngualrJS as good as you were using it inside the `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I found ng-ckeditor to implement ckeditor in angularjs. 
Please refer this :https://github.com/esvit/ng-ckeditor. I tried it, It is easy to implement and working as expected

Comment: Yes I also found it. But I started using plain java script version of the ck editor. So I faced these issues. :)